# barra de progreso con Bootstrap

Tags: php, bootstrap, progressbar

encontré una barra de progreso en Bootstrap el problema que encontré al implementarla es que no logro que la barra avance dependiendo de un variable que genero en la parte de arriba mi pregunta es voy bien o hay una forma mas sencilla para hacerlo el código es el siguiente

```
<div class="jumbotron">
                <?php
                echo'<h2>' . $obj->getDescripcion() . '</h2>';
                echo'<h2>' . $total. '</h2>';
                if ($total == $time) {
                echo'<p>se cumplio el objetivo</p>';
                } else {
                echo'<p>no se esta cumpliendo el objetivo</p>';
                }
                $progreso = ($total/$time)*100;
               echo $progreso."%";

                echo'<div class = "progress">';
                echo'<div class = "progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role = "progressbar" aria-valuenow = "60" aria-valuemin = "0" aria-valuemax = "100" style = "width:$progreso;">'.$progreso.'';
                echo'</div>';
                echo'</div>';
                echo'</div>';
                echo'<p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>';
                echo'</div>';
                ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: Tienes que actualizar la barra del lado del cliente.  De otro modo siempre va a tener el mismo valor

Comment: y donde se actualiza esa parte ?

Comment: En javascript, podrias usar ajax para chequear el progreso de tu proceso cada cierto tiempo y retornar la variable `$progreso`

Comment: ¿Cómo se supone que podría avanzar esa barra? Pareciera que el valor de `$progreso` siempre será fijo. Sea como sea, para animarla tendrías que ir variando el estilo `width` acorde al progreso. De paso, el ancho de la barra debiera ser `style = "width:{$progreso}%;"`, sin el porcentaje son pixeles

Comment: @amenadiel lo puse como dijiste echo'<div class = "progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role = "progressbar" aria-valuenow = "60" aria-valuemin = "0" aria-valuemax = "100" style = "width:{$progreso}%;">'.$progreso.''; pero la barra aparece en blanco

Comment: Y cuáles son los valores de $total y $time? Qué sale si miras el código HTML usando CTRL+U?

Comment: @amenadiel muchas gracias ya logre que funcionara haciéndolo así  echo'<div class = "progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role = "progressbar" aria-valuenow = "60" aria-valuemin = "0" aria-valuemax = "100" style = "width:' . number_format($progreso, 2) . '%;">' . $progreso;